# Вызов метода вне класса

Tags: c++

Функция вызывается в классе, ей передается указатель на метод.

```
timer (300, &Myclass::Func);
```

Передается, вроде, правильно. Но при вызове ничего не происходит. Понимаю, что без объекта вызов не имеет смысла, но как решить проблему?

```
void timer (float diff, void (Myclass::*ptrFunc) ()) // не является членом класса
{
    static clock_t t1=clock (), t2;
    t2=clock ();

    if ((float)t2-(float) t1>=diff) 
    {
        ptrFunc;
        t1=clock ();
    }
}
```

Метод который должен сработать (находится в Myclass)

```
void Func ()
{
    cout<<"Func\n";
}
```

Comment: "как решить проблему" - статическим методом

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы не вызываете функцию. `ptrFunc;` — это не вызов (в отличие от Паскаля). Это просто тривиальное арифметическое выражение, результат которого не используется, и поэтому игнорируется. Точно так же вы могли бы написать

```
14;
```

---

Существуют разные методы справиться с проблемой.

1. Вы должны каким-то образом передать экземпляр класса, у которого функция будет вызываться. Это старый способ, должен работать на практически всех компиляторах.
2. Вы можете использовать `std::function` в принимающий функции. Чтобы построить `std::function` из функции-члена, можно использовать `std::bind`, чтобы «подшить» экземпляр класса к функции. Или применить обычную лямбду.

Пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class C
{
public:
    void func() { std::cout << "I'm C::func()" << std::endl; }
};

typedef void (C::*ptrFunc)();

void call1(C* pC, ptrFunc f)
{
    (pC->*f)();
}

void call2(std::function<void()> f)
{
    f();
}

int main()
{
    C c;
    call1(&c, &C::func);
    call2(std::bind(&C::func, &c));
    call2([&c]() { c.func(); });
    return 0;
}
```

([проверка](http://ideone.com/78DP2j))

Обратите внимание, что на момент вызова переданной функции исходный объект (на котором функция будет вызываться) *обязан* существовать, и забота об этом лежит исключительно на программисте (то есть, на вас).

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, вариант с `std::function`, для человека может быть не очевидно, как его использовать(bind, лямбда)

Comment: @ixSci: Сделал.

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Comment: @Dmitry: Пожалуйста!